# Powershell start process with runas and credentials

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a process with a hardcoded user and pwd however i seem to only be able to specify either the credential or runas, but never both:

```bsh
$username = "[redacted]"
$password = "[redacted]"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))


# Self-elevate the script if required
# From:  https://blog.expta.com/2017/03/how-to-self-elevate-powershell-script.html
if (-Not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) {
 if ([int](Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BuildNumber) -ge 6000) {
  $CommandLine = "-noexit -noprofile -File `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "`" " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
   Start-Process Powershell -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine # work, but no credential
  # Start-Process PowerShell -Cred $credentials -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine # both credential and runas, doesnt work.
  Exit
 }
}
```

How can i run `Start-Process` with both credentials and runas?

Comment: There must be a parameter set that differentiates between -verb parameter and -credential. My guess is it's designed to run that way

Comment: welp i'm used to c# so powershell works magically in some areas. I know from .NET i can surely do both of these.

Comment: Why do you need both? If you specify `-Verb runas` and the current user is not a member of the local `Administrators` group, the system will prompt for administrative credentials.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart well, i'm trying to elevate myself. For that i need to run the script as an user part of the `administrators` group, and i need `runas` to elevate the process. I don't want it to prompt for anything. I use this script to reset a faulty GPU driver, meaning that the display does not work till i reset it.

Comment: "I don't want it to prompt for anything" - then you can't do what you want. The problem is that the UAC prompt will always ask for credentials - this is by design for security reasons. (If this were possible, all malware would take advantage of this.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart like i mentioned before, i have a similar mechanism in C#.NET. The builtin administrator account silently ignores UAC because of backwards compatibility reasons. I believe that other mechanism abusses that fact to get around the prompt. I just need to call start-process with both the administrator account and runas.

Comment: Well unfortunately, we can't always get what we want.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart That's perhaps very true. Anyways thanks for thinking with me.